# kill method chain in php

Tags: php, methods, method-chaining

hi i have a method chain in php somewhat like

```
<?php
auth::('username') -> is_logged() -> doSomething();
//execute something
?>
```

what i would like to do is if the user is not logged then not invoke the doSomething() function. One way is to unset $this but that would generate an error id there any other way to do it. Also i cant be using die() because it would stop the compiler and prevent codes written afterwards from executing. What is the best way to do it preferably without any warning or error and at the same time making as few changes as possible because of a large number of functions associated with the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return [NullObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) which will provide empty implementation of doSomething

In PHP you only need to provide the magic `__call()` method, so any function call will pass.

```
class NullObject {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

To use it in your class:

```
public function is_logged() {
    if ($this->user_is_logged()) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        return new NullObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: in PHP it is generating a Fatal Error, Call to member function doSomething() on a non object

Comment: @georoot this is not a null object. Null object is an object with the same interface but empty implementation.

Comment: i am not sure by that. Do you want me to initialize a new object for the current class. If no can you please edit the code i sent and explain. Thanks

Comment: He doesn't mean `(object)null`. He means `new NullObject`.

Comment: i checked it up i think i php it is called stdClass. When i worked on it, It shows call to undefined method . Is there any other thing it is called in php ?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the answer to provide sample code which can be copied and pasted.